# Prime Numbers in a sequence

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am taking a course on number theory this semester, and I am trying to come up with an idea for a term paper/project.

I am curious if the following problem is useful or has been solved? Given a sequence of say $n$ integers, can one predict whether the $n+1$ integer will be a prime? So, for example, given the sequence:

$1,2,3,4$ does knowing that the three numbers the precede 4 indicate that 4 is not a prime number somehow. Or, a sequence like, $2660, 2661, 2662, 2663$ indicate that 2663 is a prime number given 2660, 2661, 2662, etc?

I'm curious if this problem is worthwhile researching or if it has been solved?

Thanks.

Comment: Other than one counterexamples, any sequence of $2$ or more naturals will have at least one non-prime, so I don't get this question?

Comment: What do you mean when you say a sequence "indicate" that the next number is prime or not?

Comment: You can use probability to make an argument like this. The more prime numbers in some sequence you have means the probability of the next term in the sequence is less likely to be prime, and analogously, a run of composite numbers would increase the probability that the next term is prime. You would need to formalize this to make it a viable project. I don’t think this has been done formally but it would probably be a good project for an undergraduate course.

Comment: The prime gaps (distance between consecutive primes) are unbounded , hence no matter how many consecutive numbers are written down we can without checking them for primality after some trial division to reduce the effort never be sure that we have a prime number in this sequence.